# Jest's expect(value).toBeInstanceOf(Class) fails for expect(util.promisify(...)()).toBeInstanceOf(Promise) and others

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Setup:

- **jest:** 21.2.1
- **node:** 10.16.3
- **npm:** 6.9.0

Why is it that Jest's expect does not recognize promises returned by node.js' util.promisify as instances of Promise?

The following fails:

```js
const util = require('util');

const fn = util.promisify((opts, cb) => cb(null, {})); 
const promise = fn();
expect(promise).toBeInstanceOf(Promise)
```

Likewise, the following fails:

```
const util = require('util');

const fn = util.promisify((opts, cb) => cb(null, {}));
const promise = fn();
expect(promise.then).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
```

The problem can be circumvented by doing a check for `typeof promise.then` to be 'function', but I'm interested in the why of this behaviour.

Thanks a lot for the info!

Comment: It might be returning something that implements the Promise interface but it isn't an instance of `Promise`.

Comment: Understandably, but then why is the promise.then instanceof Function fails? It's returning something that is callable but is not a function? O.o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a longstanding bug in Jest titled ["Jest globals differ from Node globals"](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2549). This severely limits the effectiveness of the `toBeInstanceOf` method, unless you're testing against an instance of one of your own classes. For now, the simplest workaround is to simply test `expect(fn().constructor.name).toBe('Promise')`, fully understanding that is much more limited in its usefulness than `instanceof`. It is better than nothing, as it doesn't appear the Jest bug will be fixed in the near future.

I also might suggest that your example test is unnecessary because you're kinda testing the internals of `util.promisify`, but I understand this might just be a MVP of a larger problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! It was a minimal example for reproductibility, but yes I agree with you :)